# Database extraction performance estimation in production

Tags: database, performance, oracle, plsql

I am writing a procedure to extract data from a table A to txt file. The table in development db is having 100+ thousands rows of data. But in production db is having millions rows of data. 
How am I going to estimated the performance time required if the procedure apply to production db?
Am I need to pump in data as many as production?

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is the hardware. Almost sure the production is better than dev.
If you have access to production you can use the same procedure to extract from a copy of the table (with let's say 1 milion rows) and after that you can suppose the time for extraction is proportional.
If there is no other variable in the ecuation, you can make a proportion between dev and prod using disks speed or cpu speed (depends of what is the type of your process: more computing or more I/O.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to a test run on the production. 
It's not just the hardware or the no. or records. You have to consider the load on the production system. 
So it's not safe to predict anything just based on the hardware capacity or the no. of records.

Even in the off-peak hours, production database may be supporting report generations and ETL systems.